# Creating a form with nested attributes and prompt (has_many association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

So the issue is i have these classes.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :text_fields
    has_many :integer_fields

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :text_fields
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :integer_fields
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :fields
end

class TextField < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end

class IntegerField < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

`Category` has many `Fields`, every field (not to confuse with `TextField` or `IntegerField`) has a column "`type`" (to specify if it is Text or Integer field) and description (eg. "how many pets do you have" for integerField). When User want to create a new post, first he chooses category. then, based on what `Fields` each category has, proper `TextFields` and `IntegerFields` should be build and rendered.
I hope my point is clear, i want to have Post generator which generate different fields based on category, simple as that.

Post form (without steps for now)

```
= simple_form_for @poster do |f|
    = f.input :category_id, collection: Category.all, prompt: "Choose category"
    = f.input :title
    = f.simple_fields_for :text_fields do |ftf|
        = ftf.input :description
    = f.simple_fields_for :integer_fields do |fif|
        = fif.input :integer_number 

    = f.submit
```

And heres whats wrong. i dont know how to give each field a proper prompt. each TextField or IntegerField is there just because `Category` requires it (based on fields). But can i make it has a proper prompt, not just '`integer number`' every time?

Here's how i build those fields, its open for changes:

```
  def build_fields_based_on_category
    category.fields.each do |field|
      self.send("#{field.kind}_fields").build
      ##### 'kind' can be integer or 'text'
    end    
  end
```